# Javascript toString making no sense to me

Tags: javascript, syntax

OK I just did it and scratched my head for a while. I tried following on my Chrome console:

```
var a = [];
toString.call(a); //[object Array]
a.toString(); //""
toString(a); //[object Object] I know it's blunder but still!
```

What is difference between the toString and .toString I definitely know they are from different scopes (objects), but which one should be used at what time? Why is it so messy?

Comment: Try adding elements to the array and call its `a.toString()` method, you'll see a difference.

Comment: toString.call(a) should be == a.toString() // Just a consistency thought

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all we have to clarify that `toString` refers to `Object.prototype.toString`:

```
> toString === Object.prototype.toString
  true
```

How `Object.prototype.toString` works is explained in [section 15.2.4.2 of the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.2):

> 1. If the `this` value is `undefined`, return `"[object Undefined]"`.
> 2. If the `this` value is `null`, return `"[object Null]"`.
> 3. Let `O` be the result of calling `ToObject` passing the `this` value as the argument.
> 4. Let `class` be the value of the `[[Class]]` internal property of `O`.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings `"[object "`, `class`, and `"]"`.

`toString.call(a)` is the same as `Object.prototype.toString.call(a)` and works according to the above algorithm: `this` refers to the array `a` (because you used `.call`), the internal `[[Class]]` property has the value `Array`, hence the output is `[object Array]`.

`a.toString()`: Arrays overwrite the `toString` property, which is defined in [section 15.4.4.2](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.2). In short, all array elements are concatenated and since the array is empty, you get an empty string as result.

`toString(a)` is the same as `Object.prototype.toString()`. The argument is simply ignored. Therefore `this` refers to `Object.prototype`, which is an object and according to the algorithm mentioned above, the output is `[object Object]`. The output would be same for any value of `a`.

---

> which one should be used at what time?

That depends on what you want to do. Personally I find none of the built-in `toString` functions particularly useful, besides for some quick and dirty debugging.

---

> `toString.call(a)` should be `== a.toString()`

Well, `Object.prototype.toString` and `Array.prototype.toString` are simply two different methods, hence you get different results.

You could argue that  `Object.prototype.toString` should call the overwritten `toString` if it exists, but that's just not how `toString` is implemented.